# My JavaMail app works fine on Emulator but it is not working on my android mobile device

Tags: android

when i run my app on emulator it sends Email (as i expected )but when i try to run my app on device its says  "There was a problem sending the email." ..... 
I have already added 3 jar files i-e mail.jar,additional,activational 
i have already added internet permission in manifest ...

code is here

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View view) { 
        Mail m = new Mail("XXXXXX@gmail.com", "password"); 

        String[] toArr = {"send to @yahoo.com"}; 
        //m.send()
        m.setTo(toArr); 
        m.setFrom("YXY@gmail.com"); 
        m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
        m.setBody("Email body."); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "okkk setting.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try { 
       //   m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

          if(m.send()) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          } else { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
          } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was a problem sending the email.",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        //  Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
        } 
      } 
    }); 


}
```

**Mail.java**

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
      private String _user; 
      private String _pass; 

      private String[] _to; 
      private String _from; 

      private String _port; 
      private String _sport; 

      private String _host; 

      private String _subject; 
      private String _body; 

      private boolean _auth; 

      private boolean _debuggable; 

      private Multipart _multipart; 


      public Mail() { 
        _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
        _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
        _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

        _user = ""; // username 
        _pass = ""; // password 
        _from = ""; // email sent from 
        _subject = ""; // email subject 
        _body = ""; // email body 

        _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
        _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

        _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
      } 

      public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
        this(); 

        _user = user; 
        _pass = pass; 
      } 

      public boolean send() throws Exception { 
        Properties props = _setProperties(); 

        if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

        //  Toast.makeText(,"enter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

          msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

          InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
          for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
          } 
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

          msg.setSubject(_subject); 
          msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

          // setup message body 
          BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
          messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
          _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

          // Put parts in message 
          msg.setContent(_multipart); 

          // send email 
          Transport.send(msg); 

          return true; 
        } else { 
          return false; 
        } 
      } 

      public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
      } 

      @Override 
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
        return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
      } 

      private Properties _setProperties() { 
        Properties props = new Properties(); 

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

        if(_debuggable) { 
          props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
        } 

        if(_auth) { 
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
        } 

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

        return props; 
      } 

      // the getters and setters 
      public String getBody() { 
        return _body; 
      } 

      public void setBody(String _body) { 
        this._body = _body; 
      }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         this._to=toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._from=string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._subject=string1;
    } 

      // more of the getters and setters ….. 
    } 

////

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Hey have you get solution of this problem ..?? i am also facing this problem please help me

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution

Actually there is a api combatibilty problem

first add in onCreate method

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
      }
```

then change in manifst file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Now its working fine on my emulator + mobile device

Comment: Let me guess: This hides `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` but does not actually fix the problem of doing network I/O on UI thread. (Use e.g. an `AsyncTask` to fix that issue.)